# Getting Japanese characters to display in R Shiny

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio, rodbc

Our users have RStudio installed on their local machines and are using Shiny to filter data and exporting dataframes to an .xlsx file.

This works really well for most characters, but not when it comes to the Japanese and Mandarin ones. For those, they get to see ??????? instead of the actual text.

Data is residing in a SQL DB and we're using RODBC to connect to DB.

RODBC doesn't seem to like reading these Japanese and Mandarin characters. Is there a way to get around this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with french language the other day. Maybe these options can help you :

1. In RStudio, try going in *Tool > Global Options > Code > Saving >* and then choose the right encoding for Japanese and Mandarin. The UTF-8 enconding might work for you.
2. The blog post [Escaping from character encoding hell in R on Windows](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/) explains how to set the encoding to import external documents. It should work with data imported with RODBC as well. The autor uses Japanese characters in his examples.
3. In the `odbcDriverConnect()` function of the `RODBC` package, the argument `DBMSencoding="UTF-8"` might work for you.